# Symfony2 and Varnish - Understanding how it works

Tags: symfony, varnish

I'm running symfony2 on a Apache and Varnish in front of Apache. I configured varnish to work with symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/cache/varnish.html) and it works fine.

Now here's my problem:
I've created a twig template which displays the current time and nothing else.

```
{{ "now"|date("d/m/Y H:i:s") }}
```

Now when I reload the page I see a cache hit (varnishstat) which is a bit strange for me because I was expecting a miss since this is dynamic content.

So why do I get cache hits here? Maybe some magically added ESI tags?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your Twig template?

Answer (score 0):

Varnish don't know what "dynamic content" is ; It only know requests, responses and rules (http headers or VCL) telling whether to cache content or not.

If you don't want to cache your result, you have 2 solutions :

1 : Write specific VCL to tell Varnish not to cache :

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url = "/currentTime.php") {return (pass);}
}
```

2 : Change response cache-control header to tell Varnish (and Proxies/Browser caches) not to cache. I don't know Symfony very well but php provides necessary tools :

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Edit : Varnish only needs "cache-control" header.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my problem is that I get cache hits for dynamic content even though the time gets refreshed every reload (which doesn't make sense).

Comment: What "time" are you talking about ? If you're talking about the "Date" header, Varnish doesn't use it to determine whether to cache or not.

Comment: I'm talking about the current time in my template: `{{ "now"|date("d/m/Y H:i:s") }}`

Comment: You need to understand that when varnish caches something, it will not ask your web server if content has been updated on every request. It is the goal of caching. It will only check when cache TTL expires. If you want varnish to check if content has changed...why cache? The goal of cache is to send less requests to your web server. A cache hit is served by varnish and nothing is sent to the web server. Your web server is reached by requests only on misses (not found in cache or TTL expired) ans pass (never cached).

Comment: I understand how caching works. What I don't understand is the following: I have this template which displays the current time. If I access my Webserver directly I can see, that the seconds change every reload (as expected). But when I access this site through varnish I get a cache hit AND the time refreshes every reload. Which is strange since I did not add ESI tags.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that. So you get a cache hit but the content is updated anyway ? That's strange...and I don't see how it could be possible. Could you paste your VCL ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, varnish and your backend server work separately. So when a http request comes to Varnish, Varnish itself doesn't know anything about the content of the expected response. And that means the "dynamic content" doesn't have any difference with static content. Maybe that's what you are confused about :)